# Mass produce a bunch of barplots against several x axis variables in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a big data set of thousands of rows and 18 variables. It takes forever to make 17 separate plots when all I am doing is changing the variable on the X axis. let's pretend it's just this:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

variable1 <- c("no","yes","no","no") 
variable2 <- c("low", "medium", "medium", "high")
variable3 <- c("horrible", "bad", "terrifying", "pretty")
variable4 <- c("hm", "why", "cheese", "wine")

newish <- data.frame(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)`
```

Is there a way to mass produce (for variable 2, 3, etc) from this code chunk that I like the aesthetic of?

```
plot1 <- ggplot(newish, aes(variable1, ..count..)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Class), position = "dodge") +
     ggtitle("Lunar Phase and Accident Outcome") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
       xlab("Lunar Phase") +
        ylab("Accident Count")
```

Then I've just been plotting them all on the same window with multiplot.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to work. i.e. `..count..` ?

Comment: Perhaps because hmnoidk failed to include code that loaded a necessary package?

Comment: Sorry, I added that you need ggplot2 as a package. maybe delete count, it might be a relic from some other details I was deliberately omitting.

Comment: I do believe `..count..` is a ggplot2-defined indicator that a frequency bargraph is desired (as opposed to a histogram).

Comment: looping through column names and using [`aes_string`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) should get you close

Comment: the reason why your code is not working is that you refer to the object `Class`, which is not defined in your data frame... if it's all the same plot, why not making long data and `facet` ??

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this?

```
library(tidyverse);
newish %>%
    gather(key, value, 1:4) %>%
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
        facet_wrap(~ key, scale = "free")
```

[image]